# C# Interop World: Style text that takes many lines

Tags: c#, ms-word, styles, range, interop

I'm trying to apply style to some text in a world document using C# and  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

The text I need to style takes many lines and the code I've used is the follwing; it works properly for text in one line;

```
 string text = @"Hello World
                 how are you?";

 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para =  document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
 para.Range.Text = text;
 para.set_Style(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleListParagraph);
 para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

The result here is that the text is inserted correctly in two lines but it does not style the whole text , it styles the text line by line as a paragraph after another one.

I tried with the following

```
   para.Range.Text = text;
   para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
   Word.Range rng = para.Range;
   rng.set_Style(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleListParagraph);
```

but it does not work either.

How can I style the whole text correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> it works properly for text in one line;

You mean to say it works properly for one *paragraph*.
If you want to add and stylize text that consists of several *paragraphs* use a range instead:

```
document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
string text = @"Hello World
how are you?
";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range para = document.Range(docx.Content.End - 1, document.Content.End - 1);
para.Text = text;
para.set_Style(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleListParagraph);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works very well. I've just modified your code by eliminating the first line because it has the effect of adding an empty paragraph.